# npm --save-dev not updating node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am new to nodejs and am having trouble with npm.

Whenever I try to install something with 'npm install  --save-dev', it shows up in my devDependencies in my package.json but it never gets added to my node_modules folder.

This is what I tried:

1. Create new folder
2. npm init -y
3. npm install typescript --save-dev

Result:
In package.json I see "typescript": "^3.1.6" in my devDependencies.
No node_modules is even created.

For everyone else it does show up. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Why do you know  no node_modules is even created?

Comment: This does not replicate  on my machine. Check for other problems like disk space. Is there any error in npm ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this issue, make sure your `$NODE_ENV` wasn't accidentally set to `production`.